# Ошибка "UnityEngineRay"

Tags: unity3d

Как исправить данную ошибку. Код взял из книжки Unity в действии. У меня пишет эту ошибку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш класс `Ray` имеет такое же название, как и встроенный класс `UnityEngine.Ray`. Вы можете называть классы одинаковыми именами, только если они в разных неймспейсах, но тогда для их использования нужно писать полное имя класса.

---

В целом решения 3:

1. Переименовать свой класс

   ```
   public class MyRay : MonoBehaviour { ... }
   ```
2. Использовать полное имя класса `Ray`

   ```
   UnityEngine.Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(...);
   ```
3. Использовать ключевое слово var

   ```
   var ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(...);
   ```